# Passing flash hash from one controller to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `create` method in one controller and at the end of this controller I want `redirect_to` another controller/view. How will I be able to display a `flash[:notice]` after the first controller is done and the next `redirect_to` view is rendered?

Here's the code in the first controller:

```
if @list.save
        redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Created!"
```

I also noticed that it doesn't work here either:

```
if @list.save
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Created!"
```

Here's the routes file:

```
root :to => 'sessions#new'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To persist a flash message over an additional request you can use `flash.keep` - from [the flash section on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash):

> Let's say this action corresponds to root_url, but you want all
>   requests here to be redirected to UsersController#index. If an action
>   sets the flash and redirects here, the values would normally be lost
>   when another redirect happens, but you can use 'keep' to make it
>   persist for another request.

**Clarification:** This solution only applies if you're losing the flash due to a double redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
redirect_to(whatever_path, :notice=>"hello world")
```

Also, you can use `:error`

```
redirect_to(whatever_path, :error=>"hello error")
```

Comment: Is your layout or view outputting the `flash[:notice]` or `flash[:error]` ?

Comment: I have this in the application.html

   `<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    <% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

What version of Rails are you on? The syntax you are using is a relatively new feature. Try doing it the long way:

```
flash[:notice] = 'Created'
redirect_to root_path
```